# converting table with positive and negative values to absolute values

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

I have data saved in matrices that can be used for statistical analyses. For the purposes of my analysis I need to include all numbers in absolute values other wise the algorithm will fail. sample of the data is below:

```
NUMBER  SQUARE  SQUARE ROOT
-1  1   -1.000
2   -4  -1.414
-3  -9  1.732
-4  -16 2.000
5   25  -2.236
6   -36 -2.449
-7  49  2.646
-8  64  2.828
9   -81 3.000
10  -100    -3.162
-11 121 3.317
-12 -144    -3.464
13  169 3.606
-14 -196    -3.742
```

how can I convert the numbers in this table to absolute values.

Comment: use a text editor to delete all the minus signs

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` as follows:

```
sed 's/-//g' file | column -t
```

You can use `awk` as follows:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i < 0) $i = -$i; print }' file | column -t

NUMBER  SQUARE  SQUARE  ROOT
1       1       1.000
2       4       1.414
3       9       1.732
4       16      2.000
5       25      2.236
6       36      2.449
7       49      2.646
8       64      2.828
9       81      3.000
10      100     3.162
11      121     3.317
12      144     3.464
13      169     3.606
14      196     3.742
```

Comment: @Isaac correct! thanks for the note, applied it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to make all values positive, then just remove all the dash.

```
$ <infile sed 's/-//g'
NUMBER  SQUARE  SQUARE ROOT
1  1   1.000
2   4  1.414
3  9  1.732
4  16 2.000
5   25  2.236
6   36 2.449
7  49  2.646
8  64  2.828
9   81 3.000
10  100    3.162
11 121 3.317
12 144    3.464
13  169 3.606
14 196    3.742
```

If you need the values in nice columns add `column -t` (but also change the header line to make the third entry one word `SQUARE_ROOT`):

```
<infile sed 's/-//g' | column -t
NUMBER  SQUARE  SQUARE_ROOT
1       1       1.000
2       4       1.414
3       9       1.732
4       16      2.000
5       25      2.236
6       36      2.449
7       49      2.646
8       64      2.828
9       81      3.000
10      100     3.162
11      121     3.317
12      144     3.464
13      169     3.606
14      196     3.742
```

All could be done with one call to awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==1;NR!=1{gsub(/-/,"");printf("%5g %8g %11.3f\n",$1,$2,$3)}' infile
NUMBER  SQUARE  SQUARE_ROOT
    1        1       1.000
    2        4       1.414
    3        9       1.732
    4       16       2.000
    5       25       2.236
    6       36       2.449
    7       49       2.646
    8       64       2.828
    9       81       3.000
   10      100       3.162
   11      121       3.317
   12      144       3.464
   13      169       3.606
   14      196       3.742
```